# JMS rewrite message

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue

I know that JMS messages are immutable. But I have a task to solve, which requires rewrite message in queue by entity id. Maybe there is a problem with system design, help me please.

App A sends message (with entity id = 1) to JMS. App B checks for new messages every minute.

App A might send many messages with entity id = 1 in a minute, but App B should see just the last one.

Is it possible?

- App A should work as fast as possible, so I don't like the idea to perform removeMatchingMessages(String selector) before new message push.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the approach is flawed.

Even if you did accept clearing off the queue by using a message selector to remove all messages where entity id = 1 before writing the new message, timing becomes an issue: it's possible that whichever process writes the out-dated messages would need to complete before the new message is written, some level of synchronization.

The other solution I can think of is reading all messages before processing them.  Every minute, the thread takes the messages and bucketizes them.  An earlier entity id = 1 message would be replaced by a later one, so that at the end you have a unique set of messages to process.  Then you process them.  Of course now you might have too many messages in memory at once, and transactionality gets thrown out the window, but it might achieve what you want.

In this case you could actually be reading the messages as they come in and bucketizing them, and once a minute just run your processing logic.  Make sure you synchronize your buckets so they aren't changed out from under you as new messages come in.

But overall, not sure it's going to work